# Will signals be delivered to a program blocked on POSIX semaphore?

Tags: c, operating-system, signals, semaphore

This really is two questions, but I suppose it's better they be combined.

We're working on a client that uses asynchronous TCP connection. The idea is that the program will block until certain message is received from the server, which will invoke a SIGPOLL handler. We are using a busy waiting loop, basically:

```
var = 1
while (var) usleep(100);

//...and somewhere else
void sigpoll_handler(int signum){
    ......
    var = 0;
    ......
}
```

We would like to use something more reliable instead, like a semaphore. The thing is, when a thread is blocked on a semaphore, will the signal get through still? Especially considering that signals get delivered when it switches back to user level; if the process is off the runqueue, how will it happen?

Side question (just out of curiosity):

Without the "usleep(100)" the program never progresses past the while loop, although I can verify the variable was set in the handler. Why is that? Printing changes its behaviour too.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[too long for a comment]

Accessing `var` from inside the signal handler invokes undefined behaviour (at least for a POSIX conforming system).

From [the related POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/stage7tc1/functions/signal.html):

> [...] if the process is single-threaded and a signal handler is executed [...] the behavior is undefined if the signal handler refers to any object [...] with static storage duration other than by assigning a value to an object declared as **volatile sig_atomic_t** [...]

So `var` shall be defined:

```
volatile sig_atomic_t var;
```

---

The busy waiting `while`-loop, can be replaced by a single call to a blocking `pause()`, as it will return on reception of the signal.

From [the related POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/stage7tc1/functions/pause.html#tag_16_359):

> The *pause()* function shall suspend the calling thread until delivery of a signal whose action is either to execute a signal-catching function or to terminate the process.

Using `pause()`, btw, will make the use of any global flag like `var` redundant, to not say needless.

Comment: Undefined behaviour? No wonder the erratic ways it behaves then. Thanks so much! We already went with POSIX semaphores, and it seems to work----there wouldn't be a problem, would there?

Comment: @user3109672: In general using a semphore should do, it however still depends on the code to defintly judge. But why so complicated? Why not just setup an empty signal handler, call `pause()` instead of waiting busy or in `sem_wait()` and you' re done? And btw you save system resouces as you do not create a semphore.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes, the signal will get through fine with a good implementation.

If you're going to be using a semaphore to control the flow of the program, you'll want to have the listening be on one child with the actual data processing be on another. This will then put the concurrency fairness in the hands of the OS which will make sure your signal listening thread gets a chance to check for a signal with some regularity. It shouldn't ever be really "off the runqueue," but cycling through positions on the runqueue instead.

If it helps you to think about it, what you have right now seems to basically be a a very rough implementation of a semaphore on its own -- a shared variable whose value will stop one block of code from executing until another code block clears it. There isn't anything inherently paralyzing about a semaphore on a system level.

I kind of wonder why whatever function you're using to listen for the SIGPOLL isn't doing its own blocking, though. Most of those utilities that I've seen will stop their calling thread until they return a value. Basically they handle the concurrency for you and you can code as if you were dealing with a normal synchronous program.

With regards to the usleep loop: I'd have to look at what the optimizer's doing, but I think there are basically two possibilities. I think it's unlikely, but it could be that the no-body loop is compiling into something that isn't actually checking for a value change and is instead just looping. More likely to me would be that the lack of any body steps is messing up the underlying concurrency handling, and the loop is executing so quickly that nothing else is getting a chance to run -- the queue is being flooded by loop iterations and your signal processsing can't get a word in edgewise. You could try just watching it for a few hours to see if anything changes; theoretically if it's just a concurrency problem then the random factor involved could clear the block on its own with a few billion chances.

Comment: This is all one single thread, though---and the signal handler does execute. I'd say it's likely optimisation, but how would usleep change that?

Comment: The idea that this is all one single thread doesn't make sense to me; if this was all one synchronous thread then the while loop would block infinitely every time. There has to be some asynchronous processing happening somewhere, otherwise it'd be the same as any other program with code that's supposed to execute after an infinite loop.

Comment: We registered a signal handler using sigaction that catches SIGPOLL, indicating I/O completion

Comment: That signal handler isn't the same thread, then. There are a lot of incidental ways to create child processes without using fork()

Comment: To answer the question about the optimizer, it could theoretically be unrolling the loop an excessive number of times because it's not weighting the iteration in a way that's ideal for this use case, or it could be incorrectly dropping the variable check all together. Both of those seem less likely to me than a concurrency issue, but if it were one of them it'd probably be the loop unrolling.

Comment: Reacting to a signal definitly does not create another thread/process. @RPhillipCastagna One of the process' threads is interupted, the signal handler is run, the thread continues were having been interupted. All for the same thread.

Comment: @alk You're right in the full system sense. The point I wanted to make is that from the application code's perspective, something has to do that interruption, even if all actual processing happens in the same thread. It breaks the abstraction of the thread to say that the thread "interrupts itself," as at that point you have to start thinking about the whole implementation of the thread rather than the local one.